# I can´t configure the SSL for a custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, google-apps

Hello people and GAE/Google Apps for Business support,
We can´t configure SSL for our custom domain. Our project number is `340915567134`
We follow https://support.google.com/a/answer/2644334?hl=en ; but the "show more" link do not appear.
We follow https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl but again; we do not see it in the Google Apps for Business new control panel (security).
We have the DNS ready and verify; we have the GAE project runnig, we have billing in Google Apps and GAE.

We do not know what can be. The only thing we see in the official documentation of GAE is

> "You must have an App Engine application with billing enabled that has
>   cleared at least one billing charge; use this application when
>   enabling SSL."

The question is: must we wait for the first month to pay and then the option will be enabled (show)??

Thank you in advance,
carlos

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is too localized to a particular support incident.

Answer (score 0):

I carlos.
To do that I use a [cluodflare account Pro](http://www.cloudflare.com/). It cost 20$ per month for the first domain and 5$ per month by supplementary domain. You benefit of SSL encryption with your domain name without bye a personal certificate. In more Cloudflare provide services like DDOS protection, SPDY protocol, caching system for your site, ...